# Windows: preventing assert() failures from opening the debug popup

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, assert

How can I prevent the debug popup window from appearing when an assertion fails on a Windows machine? The app I'm writing is console based and I'm using assert() to test certain things when it's executed in test mode. I'm using MinGW + GCC 4.

Edit: This is the test program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    _set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
    assert(0 == 1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Flags: `gcc -mwindows -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c -g -Werror -MMD -MP -MF ...`

Tried without `-mwindows` as well. I still get the debug popup no matter what. This is on a Vista x86 machine.

Comment: `assert()` should print to stderr by default; the popup window only appears when you compile with the `-mwindows` flag present...

Comment: I'm not compiling with such flag.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can do that. The crudest is to redefine the `assert` macro (see the mingw `assert.h` header). You can also call (which is what I would advise):

```
_set_error_mode (_OUT_TO_STDERR);
```

**Edit:** Really, it works for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
  _set_error_mode (_OUT_TO_STDERR);
  assert (0 == 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -mwindows`, it doesn't show the dialog box at runtime. Remove the line with `_set_error_mode`, and it shows the dialog box. If it doesn't work for you, please give a complete example.

Comment: Don't you mean `_OUT_TO_STDERR` ?

Comment: This is odd. When I call the function in `main()` I get implicit function declaration and undefined macro errors. But I do have stdlib.h included and I checked the declarations myself - they're there. The macro is defined as `# define _OUT_TO_STDERR 1` and the function as `_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _set_error_mode (int);`. Any idea why I am getting the errors?

Comment: If you compile with `-ansi`, then you'll get this. Otherwise, no idea; please post a small reproducable example so we can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I compile with the -ansi flag. Do I have any other options besides the two you mentioned?

Comment: No, that's pretty much it. Don't compile with `-ansi`.

As a workaround, you can replace `_OUT_TO_STDERR` by its value 1, and ignore the warning (or copy the prototype in your own code).

But really, don't compile with `-ansi` :-)

Comment: OK, tried without the -ansi flag. Compiles fine, but the popup still appears. I'm calling the function in the first line of `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use, and that seems to work:

```
SetErrorMode (SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

Comment: This was the solution that actually worked for me. It should be added that
  `include <windows.h>` has to be added (works with MingW). For me also the `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX` was enough to set with `SetErrorMode`.